# Como passo por parâmetro em "template literal" o nome de uma propriedade especifica de um objeto em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array, objetos, parâmetros, template

A minha dúvida é o seguinte: Eu pretendo eliminar um objeto especifico através de uma propriedade **tech** que eu defini, que guarda a tecnologia á medida que adiciono através de um form em HTML.

Criei um array vazio `const myArray = []` que adiciona os objetos.

Na linha de código em baixo adiciono ao array o objeto com as propriedade **tech** e **exp**.

`myArray.push({tech: technology, exp: experience});`

Na linha de código em baixo estou a tentar passar por parâmetro em **template literal** `${technology}` o nome da minha tecnologia para uma função chamada **popUpDelete()**.

`` buttonDelete.innerHTML = '<button id="btn-removeInfo" onclick="popUpDelete(`${technology}`);" type="submit">Delete</button>'; ``

Na função em baixo recebo o meu template literal `${technology}` que foi passado por parâmetro e passo novamente esse mesmo parâmetro para a função **btnRemoveInfo(technology)**.

```
function popUpDelete(technology){
  let idDelete = document.getElementById('pop-up-container');
  if(idDelete){
    idDelete.classList.add('show');
    idDelete.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      if(e.target.className == 'btn-delete'){
        btnRemoveInfo(technology);
        idDelete.classList.remove('show');
      }else if (e.target.className == 'btn-cancel'){
        idDelete.classList.remove('show');
      }else if(e.target.id == 'close' || e.target == idDelete){
        idDelete.classList.remove('show');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Só quando esse parâmetro chegar a esta função **btnRemoveInfo(technology)** é que eu pretendo eliminar o objeto que contém o nome especifico que eu quero eliminar.

```
function btnRemoveInfo(technology){
  let indexDoObjeto;
  myArray.forEach((technology, index) => {
    if(technology.tech === technology){
      indexDoObjeto = index;
      roles.splice(indexDoObjeto, 1);
    }
  });
}
```

O problema é que ao passar por **template literal** a minha **technology** ele vai assumir: **[object HTMLInputElement]**

Comment: Onde você atribui o valor da variável `technology`? Você poderia adicionar esse trecho à sua pergunta?

Comment: E outra coisa, na função `btnRemoveInfo`, você definiu o parâmetro da _arrow function_ (no `.forEach()`) com o mesmo nome do parâmetro da função, isto é, `technology`, fazendo com que um substitua o valor do outro.

Comment: A variável technology é o nome da minha propriedade tech do objeto `{tech: technology, exp: experience}`. Ou seja, **technology** guarda o nome que eu adicionar no input no formulário.Como eu faço para pegar esse nome? Por exemplo eu escrevo no input HTML e o que eu quero é esse nome. Mas quando faço um console.log() vai retornar [object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: já tentou passar o parâmetro sem o template string ``${...}`` ?